# input[radio] in Angular.js problems undefined and unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have two problems (maybe because of the same bug):

1.) I can't **default check** one radio button in my html page. All three radioboxes are unchecked.

2.) In my code the value for *selectedValue* is always **undefined**. The other value *username* works in my code. (But the value of *selectedValue* works in the "tt" section and will be changed when i click the radio buttons)

HTML Code:

```
<input class="login__input" type="text" name="username" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">

 <div class="radio__box">
      <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedValue" value="value1" checked>
    Radio1
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedValue" value="value2">
    Radio2
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedValue" value="value3">
    Radio3
  </label><br/>

  <tt>selected = {{selectedValue}}</tt><br/>

  </div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var username = $rootScope.username; // works
var selectedValue = $rootScope.selectedValue; // undefined
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try putting the label tag before the radio button instead of nesting the radio button inside the label tag

Comment: Any chance we could see your controller code? Where do you initialize `$scope.selectedValue`?

Comment: That's the solution :D. I somehow missed it in the controller. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple plunk that demonstrates a working radio button with a default choice.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nTAcLlYIQk2Uk6887hPv?p=preview

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedValue = "value1"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Fissio pointed out, i missed to initialize the variable.